# Laravel polymorphic relationship retrieve last record

Tags: laravel, laravel-medialibrary, polymorphic-relationship

I am currently using the Spatie media library and I have created my own custom class as follows:

```
use Spatie\MediaLibrary\Models\Media as BaseMedia;

class TrybzMedia extends BaseMedia
{
    protected $table = 'media';
    protected $appends = ['url'];

    public function getUrlAttribute()
    {
        return $this->getUrl();
    }
}
```

I have a User class where I have defined a polymorphic relationship:

```
public function avatar()
{
    return $this->morphMany(TrybzMedia::class, 'model')->where('collection_name', '=', 'avatar');
}
```

There could be multiple images uploaded so what I am trying to achieve is get the last record for the relationship. I have attempted the following with no luck:

```
public function avatar()
{
    return $this->morphMany(TrybzMedia::class, 'model')->where('collection_name', '=', 'avatar')->last();
}
```

I want to contain all the code within the definition of the relationship. Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using ->limit(1) like :

```
public function avatar()
{
   return $this->morphMany(TrybzMedia::class, 'model')->where('collection_name', '=', 'avatar')->orderBy('put_column_name_here', 'DESC')->limit(1);
}
```

You can get last record.:)

Answer (score 2):

The following works:

```
public function cover()
{
    return $this->morphMany(TrybzMedia::class, 'model')
        ->where('collection_name', '=', 'cover')
        ->take(1)
        ->latest();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess this could do the job ?

```php
public function cover()
{
    $this->morphOne(TrybzMedia::class, 'model')->latestOfMany();
}
```

See the docs : [One Of Many (Polymorphic)](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships#one-of-many-polymorphic-relations)

Answer (score 0):

You can try with order by and first to get the last or first record.

```
public function avatar()
{
    return $this->morphMany(TrybzMedia::class, 'model')->where('collection_name', '=', 'avatar')->orderBy('put_column_name_here', 'DESC')->first();
}
```

Comment: adding ->first() I get the following error BadMethodCallException with message 'Call to undefined method App/TrybzMedia::addEagerConstraints()'. removing first, the results are ordered